# "replace" function examples

Tags: r

I don't find the help page for the `replace` function from the `base` package to be very *helpful*. Worst part, it has no examples which could help understand how it works.

Could you please explain how to use it? An example or two would be great.

Answer (score 44, accepted):

If you look at the function (by typing it's name at the console) you will see that it is just a simple functionalized version of the `[<-` function which is described at `?"["`. `[` is a rather basic function to R so you would be well-advised to look at that page for further details. Especially important is learning that the index argument (the second argument in `replace` can be logical, numeric or character classed values. Recycling will occur when there are differing lengths of the second and third arguments:

You should "read" the function call as" "within the first argument, use the second argument as an index for placing the values of the third argument into the first":

```
> replace( 1:20, 10:15, 1:2)
 [1]  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9  1  2  1  2  1  2 16 17 18 19 20
```

Character indexing for a named vector:

```
> replace(c(a=1, b=2, c=3, d=4), "b", 10)
 a  b  c  d 
 1 10  3  4
```

Logical indexing:

```
> replace(x <- c(a=1, b=2, c=3, d=4), x>2, 10)
 a  b  c  d 
 1  2 10 10
```

Answer (score 14):

You can also use logical tests

```
x <- data.frame(a = c(0,1,2,NA), b = c(0,NA,1,2), c = c(NA, 0, 1, 2)) 
x
x$a <- replace(x$a, is.na(x$a), 0)
x
x$b <- replace(x$b, x$b==2, 333)
```

Answer (score 12):

Here's two simple examples

```
> x <- letters[1:4]
> replace(x, 3, 'Z') #replacing 'c' by 'Z'
[1] "a" "b" "Z" "d"
> 
> y <- 1:10
> replace(y, c(4,5), c(20,30)) # replacing 4th and 5th elements by 20 and 30
 [1]  1  2  3 20 30  6  7  8  9 10
```

Answer (score 3):

Be aware that the third parameter (value) in the examples given above: the value is a constant (e.g. 'Z' or c(20,30)).

Defining the third parameter using values from the data frame itself can lead to confusion.

E.g. with a simple data frame such as this (using dplyr::data_frame):

```
tmp <- data_frame(a=1:10, b=sample(LETTERS[24:26], 10, replace=T))
```

This will create somthing like this:

```
       a     b
   (int) (chr)
1      1     X
2      2     Y
3      3     Y
4      4     X
5      5     Z
```

..etc

Now suppose you want wanted to do, was to multiply the values in column 'a' by 2, but only where column 'b' is "X". My immediate thought would be something like this:

```
with(tmp, replace(a, b=="X", a*2))
```

That will not provide the desired outcome, however. The a*2 will defined as a fixed vector rather than a reference to the 'a' column. The vector 'a*2' will thus be

```
[1]  2  4  6  8 10 12 14 16 18 20
```

at the start of the 'replace' operation. Thus, the first row where 'b' equals "X", the value in 'a' will be placed by 2. The second time, it will be replaced by 4, etc ... it will not be replaced by two-times-the-value-of-a in that particular row.

Answer (score 3):

Here's an example where I found the replace( ) function helpful for giving me insight. The problem required a long integer vector be changed into a character vector and with its integers replaced by given character values.

```
## figuring out replace( )
(test <- c(rep(1,3),rep(2,2),rep(3,1)))
```

which looks like

```
[1] 1 1 1 2 2 3
```

and I want to replace every 1 with an A and 2 with a B and 3 with a C

```
letts <- c("A","B","C")
```

so in my own secret little "dirty-verse" I used a loop

```
for(i in 1:3)
{test <- replace(test,test==i,letts[i])}
```

which did what I wanted

```
test
[1] "A" "A" "A" "B" "B" "C"
```

In the first sentence I purposefully left out that the real objective was to make the big vector of integers a factor vector and assign the integer values (levels) some names (labels).

So another way of doing the replace( ) application here would be

```
(test <- factor(test,labels=letts))
[1] A A A B B C
Levels: A B C
```

Comment: `c(rep(1,3),rep(2,2),rep(3,1))` can be reduced to `rep(1:3, 3:1)`

Comment: I appreciate your poetry snoram!