# Replace numbers in data frame column in R?

Tags: r, replace, numbers, dataframe

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Replace contents of factor column in R dataframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11810605/replace-contents-of-factor-column-in-r-dataframe)

I have the data.frame

```
df1<-data.frame("Sp1"=1:6,"Sp2"=7:12,"Sp3"=13:18)
rownames(df1)=c("A","B","C","D","E","F")

df1
  Sp1 Sp2 Sp3
A   1   7  13
B   2   8  14
C   3   9  15
D   4  10  16
E   5  11  17
F   6  12  18
```

I want to replace every entry of the number 8 in the column df1$Sp2 with the number 800. I have tried:

```
test<-replace(df1$Sp2,df1[800,"Sp2"],5)
```

Comment: For a better understanding of how to use `replace` see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11811027/replace-function-examples

Answer (score 65):

e.g.:

```
df1$Sp2[df1$Sp2 == 8] <- 800
```

Comment: @Elizabeth, why not accept the answer!

Comment: When testing this, my column gets turned into an integer, anyone else experiencing anything similar?