# Replacing occurrences of a number in multiple columns of data frame with another value in R

Tags: r, replace, indexing

**ETA:** the point of the below, by the way, is to not have to iterate through my entire set of column vectors, just in case that was a proposed solution (just do what is known to work once at a time).

---

There's plenty of examples of replacing values in a *single* vector of a data frame in R with some other value.

- [Replace a value in a data frame based on a conditional (`if`) statement in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5824173/replace-a-value-in-a-data-frame-based-on-a-conditional-if-statement-in-r)
- [replace numbers in data frame column in r [duplicate]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11817371/replace-numbers-in-data-frame-column-in-r)

And also how to replace all values of `NA` with something else:

- [How to replace all  values in a data.frame with another ( not 0) value](http://r.789695.n4.nabble.com/How-to-replace-all-lt-NA-gt-values-in-a-data-frame-with-another-not-0-value-td2125458.html)

What I'm looking for is analogous to the last question, but basically trying to replace one value with another. I'm having trouble generating a data frame of logical values mapped to my actual data frame for cases where multiple columns meet a criteria, or simply trying to do the actions from the first two questions on more than one column.

An example:

```
data <- data.frame(name = rep(letters[1:3], each = 3), var1 = rep(1:9), var2 = rep(3:5, each = 3))

data
  name var1 var2
1    a    1    3
2    a    2    3
3    a    3    3
4    b    4    4
5    b    5    4
6    b    6    4
7    c    7    5
8    c    8    5
9    c    9    5
```

And say I want all of the values of `4` in `var1` and `var2` to be `10`.

I'm sure this is elementary and I'm just not thinking through it properly. I have been trying things like:

```
data[data[, 2:3] == 4, ]
```

That doesn't work, but if I do the same with `data[, 2]` instead of `data[, 2:3]`, things work fine. It seems that logical test (like `is.na()`) work on multiple rows/columns, but that numerical comparisons aren't playing as nicely?

Thanks for any suggestions!

Answer (score 75, accepted):

you want to search through the whole data frame for any value that matches the value you're trying to replace.  the same way you can run a logical test like replacing all missing values with 10..

```
data[ is.na( data ) ] <- 10
```

you can also replace all 4s with 10s.

```
data[ data == 4 ] <- 10
```

at least i think that's what you're after?

and let's say you wanted to ignore the first row (since it's all letters)

```
# identify which columns contain the values you might want to replace
data[ , 2:3 ]

# subset it with extended bracketing..
data[ , 2:3 ][ data[ , 2:3 ] == 4 ]
# ..those were the values you're going to replace

# now overwrite 'em with tens
data[ , 2:3 ][ data[ , 2:3 ] == 4 ] <- 10

# look at the final data
data
```

Comment: I flipping swear I tried this and it wasn't working for me before. I hope to get to the point where I don't kick myself everytime I post to SO... By the way -- you're the 1min R video guy, aren't you!? Those rock.

Answer (score 5):

Basically `data[, 2:3]==4` gave you the index for `data[,2:3]` instead of `data`:

```
R > data[, 2:3] ==4
       var1  var2
 [1,] FALSE FALSE
 [2,] FALSE FALSE
 [3,] FALSE FALSE
 [4,]  TRUE  TRUE
 [5,] FALSE  TRUE
 [6,] FALSE  TRUE
 [7,] FALSE FALSE
 [8,] FALSE FALSE
 [9,] FALSE FALSE
```

So you may try this:

```
R > data[,2:3][data[, 2:3] ==4]
[1] 4 4 4 4
```

Comment: Thanks for this; also works. I just think the one from Anthony is a tad simpler. Big thanks for explaining *why* mine wasn't working though; after playing around some more, I see what you mean: me trying to apply values to data based on a comparison that was *also* subsetting makes a lot more sense.

Answer (score 2):

Just to provide a different answer, I thought I would write up a vector-math approach:

You can create a transformation matrix (really a data frame here, but will work the same), using a the vectorized 'ifelse' statement and multiply the transformation matrix and your original data, like so:

```
df.Rep <- function(.data_Frame, .search_Columns, .search_Value, .sub_Value){
   .data_Frame[, .search_Columns] <- ifelse(.data_Frame[, .search_Columns]==.search_Value,.sub_Value/.search_Value,1) * .data_Frame[, .search_Columns]
    return(.data_Frame)
}
```

To replace all values 4 with 10 in the data frame 'data' in columns 2 through 3, you would use the function like so:

```
# Either of these will work.  I'm just showing options.
df.Rep(data, 2:3, 4, 10)
df.Rep(data, c("var1","var2"), 4, 10)

#   name var1 var2
# 1    a    1    3
# 2    a    2    3
# 3    a    3    3
# 4    b   10   10
# 5    b    5   10
# 6    b    6   10
# 7    c    7    5
# 8    c    8    5
# 9    c    9    5
```

Comment: `test` should be `data`, no?  :)

Answer (score 1):

Just for continuity

```
    data[,2:3][ data[,2:3] == 4 ] <- 10
```

But it looks ugly, So do it in 2 steps is better.