# subset using `[`, explain NA output

Tags: r

If we have his data [recentely used here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14737773/replacing-occurrences-of-a-number-in-multiple-columns-of-data-frame-with-another):

```
data <- data.frame(name = rep(letters[1:3], each = 3), 
                   var1 = rep(1:9), var2 = rep(3:5, each = 3))

  name var1 var2
1    a    1    3
2    a    2    3
3    a    3    3
4    b    4    4
5    b    5    4
6    b    6    4
7    c    7    5
8    c    8    5
9    c    9    5
```

we  can look for rows where var2 == 4.

```
data[data[,3] == 4 ,] # equally data[data$var2 == 4 ,]

#  name var1 var2
#4    b    4    4
#5    b    5    4
#6    b    6    4
```

or rows where both var1 and var2 ==4

```
data[data[,2] == 4 &  data[,3] == 4,]

#  name var1 var2
#4    b    4    4
```

what I dont get is why this:

```
data[ data[ , 2:3 ] == 4 ,]
```

gives this:

```
     name var1 var2
4       b    4    4
NA   <NA>   NA   NA
NA.1 <NA>   NA   NA
NA.2 <NA>   NA   NA

#I would still hope to get 
 #  name var1 var2
#4    b    4    4
```

Where do the NAs come from?

Comment: I think thats a rough downvote.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `data[,2:3]==4` is the following :

```
R> data[,2:3]==4
       var1  var2
 [1,] FALSE FALSE
 [2,] FALSE FALSE
 [3,] FALSE FALSE
 [4,]  TRUE  TRUE
 [5,] FALSE  TRUE
 [6,] FALSE  TRUE
 [7,] FALSE FALSE
 [8,] FALSE FALSE
 [9,] FALSE FALSE
```

Then you try to index the rows of your data frame with this matrix. To do this, R seems to first convert your matrix to a vector :

```
R> as.vector(data[,2:3]==4)
 [1] FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
[12] FALSE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE
```

It then selects the rows of `data` based on this vector. The 4th `TRUE` value selects the 4th row, but the three others `TRUE` values select "out of bounds" rows, so they return `NA`'s.

Answer (score 3):

Your logical that you're subsetting on is a matrix:

```
> sel <- data[ , 2:3 ] == 4
> sel
       var1  var2
 [1,] FALSE FALSE
 [2,] FALSE FALSE
 [3,] FALSE FALSE
 [4,]  TRUE  TRUE
 [5,] FALSE  TRUE
 [6,] FALSE  TRUE
 [7,] FALSE FALSE
 [8,] FALSE FALSE
 [9,] FALSE FALSE
```

According to `help("[.data.frame")`:

> Matrix indexing (x[i] with a logical or a 2-column integer matrix i)
>   using [ is not recommended, and barely supported. For extraction, x is
>   first coerced to a matrix. For replacement, a logical matrix (only)
>   can be used to select the elements to be replaced in the same way as
>   for a matrix.

But that implies this form:

```
> data[ sel ]
[1] "b" "4" "5" "6" "4"
```

Badness.  What you're doing is even less sensical, though, in that you're telling it you want only the rows (with your trailing comma), and then giving it a matrix to index on!

```
> data[sel,]
     name var1 var2
4       b    4    4
NA   <NA>   NA   NA
NA.1 <NA>   NA   NA
NA.2 <NA>   NA   NA
```

If you really wanted to use the matrix form, you could use `apply` to apply a logical operation across rows.

Comment: +1 thanks for the clarification, I knew it was the wrong way I just didn't know why. Also I know help but hope you realise `help("[.data.frame")` might be a bit obscure to the uninitiated.

Answer (score 0):

```
    data[ data[ , 2 ] == 4 | data[,3] == 4,]

    name  var1 var2
 4    b    4    4
 5    b    5    4
 6    b    6    4
```

I suspect your method does not work because c() builds a vector, whereas you need to compare the atomic elements.

Answer (score 0):

Because you're not passing a vector but a matrix to the index:

```
> data[ , 2:3 ] == 4
       var1  var2
 [1,] FALSE FALSE
 [2,] FALSE FALSE
 [3,] FALSE FALSE
 [4,]  TRUE  TRUE
 [5,] FALSE  TRUE
 [6,] FALSE  TRUE
 [7,] FALSE FALSE
 [8,] FALSE FALSE
 [9,] FALSE FALSE
```

If you want the matrix collapsed into a vector that indexing works with here are two options:

```
data[ apply(data[ , 2:3 ] == 4, 1, all) ,]
data[ rowSums(data[ , 2:3 ] == 4) == 2 ,]
```