# R: Replace multiple values in multiple columns of dataframes with NA

Tags: r, replace, dataframe, multiple-columns

I am trying to achieve something similar to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14737773/replacing-occurrences-of-a-number-in-multiple-columns-of-data-frame-with-another) but with multiple values that must be replaced by NA, and in large dataset.

```
df <- data.frame(name = rep(letters[1:3], each = 3), foo=rep(1:9),var1 = rep(1:9), var2 = rep(3:5, each = 3))
```

which generates this dataframe:

```
df
  name foo var1 var2
1    a   1    1    3
2    a   2    2    3
3    a   3    3    3
4    b   4    4    4
5    b   5    5    4
6    b   6    6    4
7    c   7    7    5
8    c   8    8    5
9    c   9    9    5
```

I would like to replace all occurrences of, say, 3 and 4 by NA, but only in the columns that start with "var".

I know that I can use a combination of `[]` operators to achieve the result I want:

```
df[,grep("^var[:alnum:]?",colnames(df))][ 
        df[,grep("^var[:alnum:]?",colnames(df))] == 3 |
        df[,grep("^var[:alnum:]?",colnames(df))] == 4
   ] <- NA

df
  name foo var1 var2
1    a   1    1    NA
2    a   2    2    NA
3    a   3    NA   NA
4    b   4    NA   NA
5    b   5    5    NA
6    b   6    6    NA
7    c   7    7    5
8    c   8    8    5
9    c   9    9    5
```

Now my questions are the following:

1. Is there a way to do this in an efficient way, given that my actual
   dataset has about 100.000 lines, and 400 out of 500 variables start
   with "var". It seems (subjectively) slow on my computer when I use
   the double brackets technique.
2. How would I approach the problem if
   instead of 2 values (3 and 4) to be replaced by NA, I had a long
   list of, say, 100 various values? Is there a way to specify multiple values with having to do a clumsy series of conditions separated by `|` operator?

Comment: You could use `%in%`.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can also do this using `replace`:

```
sel <- grepl("var",names(df))
df[sel] <- lapply(df[sel], function(x) replace(x,x %in% 3:4, NA) )
df

#  name foo var1 var2
#1    a   1    1   NA
#2    a   2    2   NA
#3    a   3   NA   NA
#4    b   4   NA   NA
#5    b   5    5   NA
#6    b   6    6   NA
#7    c   7    7    5
#8    c   8    8    5
#9    c   9    9    5
```

Some quick benchmarking using a million row sample of data suggests this is quicker than the other answers.

Comment: On my data I went from 17 seconds to 1.8 seconds, a ten-fold decrease compared to @akrun method! Thanks!

Comment: Any idea whether it is possible to count how many values have been changed?

Answer (score 7):

You could also do:

```
col_idx <- grep("^var", names(df))
values <- c(3, 4)
m1 <- as.matrix(df[,col_idx])
m1[m1 %in% values] <- NA
df[col_idx]  <- m1
df
#   name foo var1 var2
#1    a   1    1   NA
#2    a   2    2   NA
#3    a   3   NA   NA
#4    b   4   NA   NA
#5    b   5    5   NA
#6    b   6    6   NA
#7    c   7    7    5
#8    c   8    8    5
#9    c   9    9    5
```

Comment: Thank you. With my data, this solution turns out to be 6 or 7 times faster than the `sapply` method.

Comment: @Peutch - I think I've squeezed a fraction more speed out of this with `replace` - could you test on your actual data?

Answer (score 7):

Since **dplyr** 1.0.0 (early 2020), I believe the dplyr approach would be:

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% mutate(across(starts_with('var'), ~replace(., . %in% c(3,4), NA)))

  name foo var1 var2
1    a   1    1   NA
2    a   2    2   NA
3    a   3   NA   NA
4    b   4   NA   NA
5    b   5    5   NA
6    b   6    6   NA
7    c   7    7    5
8    c   8    8    5
9    c   9    9    5
```

An alternative approach using the **naniar** package, which neatly imputes missing values to selected columns using a predicate function (here with `str_detect()`):

```
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)
library(naniar)

df%>%replace_with_na_if(str_detect(names(.), '^var'), ~.%in%c(3,4))
```

It would be very nice to see the naniar package updated to work with current tidyselect synthax with `across()`, and its selection helpers, with something like:
`df%>%mutate(across(starts_with('var'), replace_with_na_all(condition=~.%in% c(3, 4))))`

Answer (score 4):

Here's an approach:

```
# the values that should be replaced by NA
values <- c(3, 4)

# index of columns
col_idx <- grep("^var", names(df))
# [1] 3 4

# index of values (within these columns)
val_idx <- sapply(df[col_idx], "%in%", table = values)
#        var1  var2
#  [1,] FALSE  TRUE
#  [2,] FALSE  TRUE
#  [3,]  TRUE  TRUE
#  [4,]  TRUE  TRUE
#  [5,] FALSE  TRUE
#  [6,] FALSE  TRUE
#  [7,] FALSE FALSE
#  [8,] FALSE FALSE
#  [9,] FALSE FALSE

# replace with NA
is.na(df[col_idx]) <- val_idx

df
#   name foo var1 var2
# 1    a   1    1   NA
# 2    a   2    2   NA
# 3    a   3   NA   NA
# 4    b   4   NA   NA
# 5    b   5    5   NA
# 6    b   6    6   NA
# 7    c   7    7    5
# 8    c   8    8    5
# 9    c   9    9    5
```

Answer (score 4):

<s>I haven't timed this option, but</s> I have written a function called [`makemeNA`](https://github.com/mrdwab/SOfun/blob/master/R/makemeNA.R) that is part of [my GitHub-only "SOfun" package](https://github.com/mrdwab/SOfun).

With that function, the approach would be something like this:

```
library(SOfun)

Cols <- grep("^var", names(df))
df[Cols] <- makemeNA(df[Cols], NAStrings = as.character(c(3, 4)))
df
#   name foo var1 var2
# 1    a   1    1   NA
# 2    a   2    2   NA
# 3    a   3   NA   NA
# 4    b   4   NA   NA
# 5    b   5    5   NA
# 6    b   6    6   NA
# 7    c   7    7    5
# 8    c   8    8    5
# 9    c   9    9    5
```

---

The function uses the `na.strings` argument in `type.convert` to do the conversion to `NA`.

---

Install the package with:

```
library(devtools)
install_github("SOfun", "mrdwab")
```

(or your favorite method of installing packages from GitHub).

---

Here's some benchmarking. I've decided to make things interesting and replace both numeric and non-numeric values with `NA` to see how things compare.

Here's the sample data:

```
n <- 1000000
set.seed(1)
df <- data.frame(
  name1 = sample(letters[1:3], n, TRUE), 
  name2 = sample(letters[1:3], n, TRUE),
  name3 = sample(letters[1:3], n, TRUE),
  var1 = sample(9, n, TRUE), 
  var2 = sample(5, n, TRUE),
  var3 = sample(9, n, TRUE))
```

Here are the functions to test:

```
fun1 <- function() {
  Cols <- names(df)
  df[Cols] <- makemeNA(df[Cols], NAStrings = as.character(c(3, 4, "a")))
  df
}

fun2 <- function() {
  values <- c(3, 4, "a")
  col_idx <- names(df)
  m1 <- as.matrix(df)
  m1[m1 %in% values] <- NA
  df[col_idx]  <- m1
  df
}

fun3 <- function() {
  values <- c(3, 4, "a")
  col_idx <- names(df)
  val_idx <- sapply(df[col_idx], "%in%", table = values)
  is.na(df[col_idx]) <- val_idx
  df
}

fun4 <- function() {
  sel <- names(df)
  df[sel] <- lapply(df[sel], function(x) 
    replace(x, x %in% c(3, 4, "a"), NA))
  df
}
```

I'm breaking out `fun2` and `fun3`. I'm not crazy about `fun2` because it converts everything to the same type. I also expect `fun3` to be slower.

```
system.time(fun2())
#    user  system elapsed 
#    4.45    0.33    4.81 

system.time(fun3())
#    user  system elapsed 
#   34.31    0.38   34.74
```

So now it comes down to me and Thela...

```
library(microbenchmark)
microbenchmark(fun1(), fun4(), times = 50)
# Unit: seconds
#    expr      min       lq   median       uq      max neval
#  fun1() 2.934278 2.982292 3.070784 3.091579 3.617902    50
#  fun4() 2.839901 2.964274 2.981248 3.128327 3.930542    50
```

Dang you Thela!

Comment: +1 I converted it to matrix as the example showed `numeric` columns to compare

Answer (score 1):

I think `dplyr` is very well-suited for this task.
Using `replace()` as suggested by @thelatemail, you could do something like this:

```
library("dplyr")
df <- df %>% 
  mutate_at(vars(starts_with("var")),
            funs(replace(., . %in% c(3, 4), NA)))

df
#   name foo var1 var2
# 1    a   1    1   NA
# 2    a   2    2   NA
# 3    a   3   NA   NA
# 4    b   4   NA   NA
# 5    b   5    5   NA
# 6    b   6    6   NA
# 7    c   7    7    5
# 8    c   8    8    5
# 9    c   9    9    5
```

Comment: funs is deprectated

Answer (score -3):

Here is a dplyr solution:

```
# Define replace function
repl.f <- function(x) ifelse(x%in%c(3,4), NA,x)

library(dplyr)
cbind(select(df, -starts_with("var")),
  mutate_each(select(df, starts_with("var")), funs(repl.f)))

  name foo var1 var2
1    a   1    1   NA
2    a   2    2   NA
3    a   3   NA   NA
4    b   4   NA   NA
5    b   5    5   NA
6    b   6    6   NA
7    c   7    7    5
8    c   8    8    5
9    c   9    9    5
```

Comment: I don't think using `mutate_each()` or it's up-to-date equivalent `mutate_all()` in this way makes sense (anymore). I'm not sure if this was possible in 2015 but nowadays you should use `mutate_at(vars(starts_with("var"), ...)` which is both more elegant and faster than the `mutate_each()`-`select()`-`cbind()`-approach

Comment: Agree with statmerkur, try instead using updated dplyr language, mutate(across(...)) as has been noted elsehwere.