# R: Change NA in 1000s of columns to the value of another column

Tags: r, replace, nas

I found sort of the reverse question here:  [R: Replace multiple values in multiple columns of dataframes with NA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25768305/r-replace-multiple-values-in-multiple-columns-of-dataframes-with-na)

But I couldn't make it work with my data.  In my case, I want to find the NA's and replace them with the value from another column.

I have a dataset dta1 in which there are 2493 variables I am interested in manipulating.  Aside from these 2493 variables there's a column var_fill.  When any of the columns named in vars is NA I want to fill it in with the value from var_fill.  I tried reverse engineering the solution posted above but it gives me multiple warnings of:

```
1: In `[<-.factor`(`*tmp*`, list, value = structure(c(16946L,  ... :   invalid factor level, NA generated  
2: In x[...] <- m :   number of items to replace is not a multiple of replacement length
```

And also just doesn't work.

```
vars <- sprintf("var%0.4d",seq(1:2493))

dta1[vars] <- lapply(dta1[vars], function(x) replace(x,is.na(x), dta1$var_fill) )
```

I apologize but because of the size of this data I couldn't generate a full reproducible dataset so I heavily subsetted it but I am working with about 3000 columns and 240K rows of data.

Here's the data:  https://drive.google.com/file/d/1oj_nhd99ftgN1Bh930_IRQftLACR2FO9/view?usp=sharing

It's too big to post even though it's only 10 people.

Comment: have you tried `dta1[vars] <- lapply(dta1[vars], function(x) ifelse(is.na(x), dta1$var_fill, x))` instead? you'll need to coerce the factor variables to character to avoid those warnings, you can do that when you read in the data

Comment: Do you want to replace all NA row values in that row with the var_fill column value at that row, or something more exotic?

Comment: You don't need to share with us all the data. A sample dataframe with 10 rows and 4-5 columns along with expected output would be enough to help us understand the problem.

Comment: @rawr, I tried that but it did a couple of strange things so I went with the option below but thanks for responding!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turn the columns to characters and replace the `NA` values with the corresponding `var_fill` value.

```
dta1$var_fill <- as.character(dta1$var_fill)

dta1[vars] <- lapply(dta1[vars], function(x) {
                      x <- as.character(x)
                      x[is.na(x)] <- dta1$var_fill[is.na(x)]
                      x
                })
```

In `dplyr`, you can use `coalesce`.

```
library(dplyr)
dta1 <- dta1 %>% mutate(across(all_of(vars), ~coalesce(., var_fill)))
```

Comment: This did it!  Except it worked better to not convert var_fill to character.  When I did that it did some strange things to some of them but leaving at numeric worked great, thanks!