# Replacing occurrences of a number in specific columns from a data table

Tags: r, data.table

I've come across [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14737773/replacing-occurrences-of-a-number-in-multiple-columns-of-data-frame-with-another) post on how to replace occurrences of a number in *all* columns of a **data frame** (e.g. replace all 4 by 10 in all columns): `DF[DF == 4] <- 10`. With data tables the same results can be achieved in exactly the same way: `DT[DT == 4] <- 10`.

However, how should I procede if I want to apply this modification but only to *specific* columns from the data table, whether these columns are specified by position (e.g. `2:4`) or by name (e.g. `c("V2", "V3", "V4")`)?

I will favor an "elegant" solution rather than iterations over every column.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We can use `set` which would be more efficient

```
for(j in 2:4) {
  set(DT, i = which(DT[[j]]==4), j=j, value = 10)
 }
DT
#   V1 V2 V3 V4
#1:  A  2  2 10
#2:  B  1 10 10
#3:  C  3 10  3
#4:  D  3  2 10
#5:  E  3  3  3
#6:  F 10  3  3
```

The above can be done with column names as well

```
for(j in names(DT)[2:4]){
   set(DT, i = which(DT[[j]]==4), j=j, value = 10)
 }
```

---

Or another option is to specify the `.SDcols` with the columns of interest (either the numeric index or the column names), loop through the Subset of Data.table (`.SD`), `replace` the values that are 4 to 10 and assign (`:=`) the output back to columns of interest

```
DT[, (2:4) := lapply(.SD, function(x) replace(x, x==4, 10)), .SDcols = 2:4]
```

Or with column names

```
DT[, (names(DT)[2:4]) := lapply(.SD, function(x) replace(x, x==4, 10)), 
      .SDcols = names(DT)[2:4]]
```

#### data

```
set.seed(24)
DT <- data.table(V1 = LETTERS[1:6], V2 = sample(1:4, 6, replace = TRUE), 
   V3 = sample(2:4, 6, replace = TRUE), V4 = sample(3:4, 6, replace= TRUE))
```

Comment: This works perfectly! I would just suggest you to add one more line of code but using column names to make it clear for everyone.