# how to replace the "N" in the Same Row if any of the columns is empty in R programming

Tags: r, dataframe, tabulizer

How to replace the char "N" from the column "GID" in the same Row if any of the columns is empty

```
DataFile <- extract_tables("new.pdf",pages = c(87),
                           method = "stream", output = "data.frame", guess = TRUE)
DataFrame<-as.data.frame(DataFile)

#removing No. and A# from columns
df2<-subset(DataFrame, Group!="No." & Group!="A#")
```

**output:**

```
GID    ColA    ColB 
1       2       2
2       3       4
3       5       4
4       6       5
5       6       5
NG1     8 
MG2     8       1
MG3     8       1
NG4     8
```

**Expected output:**

```
GID    ColA    ColB 
1       2       2
2       3       4
3       5       4
4       6       5
5       6       5
G1     8       N
MG2     8       1
MG3     8       1
G4     8       N
```

**DATA:**

```
df1 <-  structure(list(GID = c("1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "NG1", "MG2", 
"MG3", "NG4"), ColA = c(2L, 3L, 5L, 6L, 6L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L), 
    ColB = c("2", "4", "4", "5", "5", "", "1", "1", "")), row.names = c(NA, 
-9L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: Check `tidyr::replace_na` for this, unless you provide us with your data we can't help further. Run `dput(DataFrame)` and paste the output here.

Comment: if it's actually "empty" rather than `NA`, sth like `ifelse(yourdata$ColB == "", "N", yourdata$ColB)` should help

Comment: @MohanGovindasamy, the request is not for "NA" values, it's for "N" values.

Comment: @tjebo, how to do it without specifying the exact "ColB"

Comment: check `dplyr` package mutate(across(everything(), ...))

Comment: @kumar as I said earlier if you give your data it will be easier for us to answer

Comment: check this thread https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14737773/replacing-occurrences-of-a-number-in-multiple-columns-of-data-frame-with-another

Comment: @MohanGovindasamy Data is added in the post

Answer (score 2):

In base R, you could try the following.

First, identify the rows where `ColB` is an empty character value, and store in a logical vector:

```
emp_rows <- df1$ColB == ""
```

Then, remove "N" in `GID` in those rows:

```
df1$GID[emp_rows] <- gsub("N", "", df1$GID[emp_rows])
```

And store "N" in `ColB` in the same rows:

```
df1$ColB[emp_rows] <- "N"
```

To generalize for any column that is blank, you can do the following. Based on the logic in the comment, first check if `GID` starts with "N". If it does, remove the "N", and then check all columns for blank values, and if blank, substitute with "N".

You can create a function to do this, and then use `apply` or other method to rowwise go through your data frame.

```
my_fun <- function(vec) {
  if (startsWith(vec[["GID"]], "N")) {
    vec[["GID"]] <- gsub("N", "", vec[["GID"]])
    vec <- replace(vec, vec == "", "N")
  }
  return(vec)
}

data.frame(t(apply(df1, 1, my_fun)))
```

**Output**

```
  GID ColA ColB
1   1    2    2
2   2    3    4
3   3    5    4
4   4    6    5
5   5    6    5
6  G1    8    N
7 MG2    8    1
8 MG3    8    1
9  G4    8    N
```

Comment: Thank You, but I should not specifically mention the empty row for ColB.  If any rows of the Column GID has the value which starts with "N" it should automatically replace the same row with any Column if it is empty

Comment: @kumar Please see edited answer, let me know if this is what you had in mind.

Comment: Like that - @kumar although this is a great solution and shows some nice and clear code using base R only, I would like to point out that what your are getting is character columns. This might intentional, but I get the feeling that it might not be what you actually want. If you want to keep your value as a "number" (an integer), I'd replace empty values with NA and create a separate column with your String

Comment: Agree with @tjebo, using NA would likely be a better approach and worth consideration depending on your needs. Once you start adding "N" to "ColA" or "ColB" they will necessarily need to be character and cannot be integer.

Answer (score 0):

By this way you can replace empty char with N or any other character if your choice without mentioning column name

```r
library(tidyverse)

df1 <- structure(list(GID = c("1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "NG1", "MG2", "MG3", "NG4"), ColA = c(2L, 3L, 5L, 6L, 6L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L), ColB = c("2", "4", "4", "5", "5", "", "1", "1", "")), row.names = c(NA, -9L), class = "data.frame")

df1 %>% 
  mutate(across(everything(), ~str_replace(., "^$", "N")),
         GID = GID %>% str_remove("N"))
#>   GID ColA ColB
#> 1   1    2    2
#> 2   2    3    4
#> 3   3    5    4
#> 4   4    6    5
#> 5   5    6    5
#> 6  G1    8    N
#> 7 MG2    8    1
#> 8 MG3    8    1
#> 9  G4    8    N
```

<sup>Created on 2021-02-05 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Comment: Thank you @Mohan Govindasamy. also, I should remove the N value from GID, If the GID starts with N then only I should replace the same into the empty row of a column

Comment: I have edited the answer to remove N from the GID column