# Replace values across time series columns based on another column

Tags: r, dplyr, replace

My question is similar to another one: [R replace specific value in many columns across dataframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69422463/r-replace-specific-value-in-many-columns-across-dataframe)

However I need to replace values based on a vector from another column rather than with NA or a constant.

Can you please help?

```
#there are many more yrs in the data set
yr1<-c("1","missing")
yr2<-c("3","4")
right<-c("2","3")
df<-data.frame(yr1,yr2,right)

df<-df %>%
  mutate(
      across(starts_with('yr'), ~replace(.x, ~.x=="missing", right) ))
```

Where `right` is another column where I want to "lookup" the value to replace the "missing" value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `ifelse` instead of `replace` should solve your problem.

```
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  mutate(across(starts_with('yr'), ~ifelse(.x=="missing", right, .x)))

#  yr1 yr2 right
#1   1   3     2
#2   3   4     3
```

In general, I would suggest to use `replace` only when you have a fixed (constant) value to replace for all other things using `ifelse` is better.

Comment: Actually I have a followup question, if I need to mutate but based on a condition on another column, what do I need instead of ```other.column```? @Ronak Shah Something like ```df %>%
  mutate(across(starts_with('yr'), ~ifelse(other.column=="C", right, .x)))```

Comment: @melange164 Exactly, that should work if `other.column` is the name of the column.

Answer (score 0):

`base R` option:

```
cols <- grep("^yr\\d+$", names(df))
df[cols][df[cols] == "missing"] <- df[df[cols] == "missing", "right"]
```

Output:

```
  yr1 yr2 right
1   1   3     2
2   3   4     3
```