# In R, replace values across time series based on another column

Tags: r, dplyr

Actually this is linked to my previous question: [Replace values across time series columns based on another column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72303553/replace-values-across-time-series-columns-based-on-another-column/72303636#72303636)

However I need to modify values across a time series data set but based on a condition from the same row but across another set of time series columns. The dataset looks like this:

```
#there are many more years (yrs) in the data set
product<-c("01","02")
yr1<-c("1","7")
yr2<-c("3","4")

#these follow the number of years
type.yr1<-c("mixed","number")
type.yr2<-c("number","mixed")

#this is a reference column to pull values from in case the type value is "mixed" 
mixed.rate<-c("1+5GBP","7+3GBP")

df<-data.frame(product,yr1,yr2,type.yr1,type.yr2,mixed.rate)
```

Where the value 1 should be replaced by "1+5GBP" and 4 should be "7+3GBP". I am thinking of something like the below -- could anyone please help?

```
df %>% 
mutate(across(c(starts_with('yr'),starts_with('type'), ~ifelse(type.x=="mixed", mixed.rate.x, .x)))
```

The final result should be:

```
product<-c("01","02")
yr1<-c("1+5GBP","7")
yr2<-c("3","7+3GBP")
type.yr1<-c("mixed","number")
type.yr2<-c("number","mixed")
mixed.rate<-c("1+5 GBP","7+3GBP")

df<-data.frame(product,yr1,yr2,type.yr1,type.yr2,mixed.rate)
```

Comment: what is your final expected result?

Comment: I have updated it with the final result!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, I think you might benefit from pivoting longer, replacing the values in a single `if_else`, and swinging back to wide.

```
df %>% 
  pivot_longer(cols = -c(product,mixed.rate), names_to=c(".value", "year"), names_pattern = "(.*)(\\d)") %>% 
  mutate(yr=if_else(type.yr=="mixed",mixed.rate,yr)) %>% 
  pivot_wider(names_from=year, values_from=c(yr,type.yr),names_sep = "")
```

Output:

```
  product mixed.rate yr1     yr2    type.yr1 type.yr2
  <chr>   <chr>      <chr>   <chr>  <chr>    <chr>   
1 01      1+5 GBP    1+5 GBP 3      mixed    number  
2 02      7+3GBP     7       7+3GBP number   mixed
```

Comment: Hi thanks I think it largely works but I need the ```rate.yr1``` and ```rate.yr2``` to come back also. How do I bring back those columns with the corresponding yr?

Comment: I mean the ```type.yr1``` and ```type.yr2```

Comment: sure, see update.

Comment: Sorry for the delayed reply - it works great, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can use `pivot_longer` to have all yrs in one column and type.yrs in another column. Then `record` 1 into 1+5GBP and 4 into 7+3GBP if the type.yr column is mixed. then `pivot_wider`

```
df %>%
  pivot_longer(contains('yr'), names_to = c('.value','grp'),
               names_pattern = '(\\D+)(\\d+)') %>%
  mutate(yr = ifelse(type.yr == 'mixed', recode(yr, '1' = '1+5GBP', '4' = '7+3GBP'), yr)) %>%
  pivot_wider(c(product, mixed.rate), names_from = grp,
              values_from = c(yr, type.yr), names_sep = '')

# A tibble: 2 x 6
  product mixed.rate yr1    yr2    type.yr1 type.yr2
  <chr>   <chr>      <chr>  <chr>  <chr>    <chr>   
1 01      1+5GBP     1+5GBP 3      mixed    number  
2 02      7+3GBP     7      7+3GBP number   mixed
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're happy to use base R instead of dplyr then the following will produce your required output:

```
for (i in 1:2) {
  df[,paste0('yr',i)] <- if_else(df[,paste0('type.yr',i)]=='mixed',df[,'mixed.rate'],df[,paste0('yr',i)])
}
```