# How to determine data point that gives error?

Tags: r, error-handling, runtime-error

I have a code in R that reads, one line at the time, through a data.frame and if a certain set of conditions is met, changes the value of one of the variables in the data.frame. In pseudo code:

```
for(i in 1:nrow(data)) {

 if (conditions on data[i,]) { change value } else {do nothing}

}
```

While the code is running, at a certain point it stops and throws the following error message: `Error in if (condition : missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed`

I understand that the error message means that, at a certain point, when the condition in the `if` statement is evaluated the result is `Na` rather than a `TRUE` or `FALSE`.

However, when I try the condition in R by using the value of `i` that is "stored" in R (and which I assume to be the row of the data set that throws the error) I get an answer of `TRUE`. Do I understand correctly that the value of `i` allows me to identify which line of the data frame is throwing the error? If not, should I look for some other way to identify which row of the data set is causing the error?

Comment: If `data` is a data.frame, you would typically use `for(i in 1:nrow(data))`.  Look at `dim(data)` to see what you get.  Also, hard to help without a **[reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/a/28481250/2725969)**.  Also, `ifelse` might be a better way to do what you are trying to do.

Comment: @BrodieG thank you for your feedback. I guess my question is more specifically asking whether I can use `i` to figure out which line of the data.frame throws the error, rather than the nature of the error itself. Is that the case? Does the value of `i` stored in R indicate the line at which the code encountered the error?

Comment: Yes, but keep in mind that `data[i]` returns the ith column, not the ith row.  For the row you need `data[i, ]`.  Also, note my comment above about `nrow` vs. `dim`.

Comment: Thank you: I have made the changes that you have suggested to my pseudo code.

Comment: @BrodieG Can you tell me what is the advantage of using `ifelse` instead of `if`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As long as your for loop is not inside a function, i will be equal to the final value it hit before the error. Thus after your error:

```
 data[i, ]
```

Should give you the pathological row.

If you are running inside a function, due to scoping rules, i should die with the function. In that case, I would modify your code to print out every line (or i) until it dies:

```
 for(i in 1:nrow(data)) {
   print(i) #or print(data[i, ])
   if (conditions on data[i,]) { change value } else {do nothing}

}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think the answer is "yes"

```
 print(i) ## Error: doesn't exist yet
 for (i in 1:10) {
     if (i==4) stop("simulated error")
 }
 print(i)  ## 4
```

The `try()` function can also be useful.  Here we make a function `f` that simulates the error, then use `try()` so that we can run all the way through the loop.  We don't stopping when we hit the error, but instead fill in a value (10000 in this case) that stands for an error code.  (We could also just make the error behaviour be a no-op, i.e. just go on to the next iteration of the loop; in this case that would leave an `NA` in the error position.)

```
 f <- function(x) {
     if (x==4) stop("simulated error")
     return(x)
 }
 results <- rep(NA,10)
 for (i in 1:10) {
     res <- try(f(i))
     if (is(res,"try-error")) {
        results[i] <- 10000
     } else {
        results[i] <- res
    }
 }
```

Comment: I think you have "lost" a `)` in your for loop. Also, I'm trying to figure out what is the for loop actually doing: can you clarify? When I run it i get the following error message: `Error in f(i) : simulated error` Is it the desired output? If so, what does it mean?

Answer (score 0):

1) replacing values

wouldn't it be better to use `replace` ?

some examples here: [replace function examples](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11811027/replace-function-examples)

in your case

```
 replace (df$column, your_condition, value)
```

2) filtering

if you're sure your data contains only TRUEs/FALSEs or NAs you can:

a) subset rows with NAs in specific column

```
df[(is.na(df$column)), ]
```

b) filter out things using `filter` from dplyr

```
library("dplyr")
filter(df, is.na(column)) # filter NAs in dplyr you don't have to use $ to specify column
filter(df, !is.na(column) & column!="FALSE") # filter everything other than NA and FALSE
filter(df, column!="TRUE" & column!="FALSE") # careful with that, won't return NAs
```

3) selecting row numbers

finally, when you need specific row number where NAs occur, use `which`

```
which(is.na(df$column)) # row numbers with NAs
which(df$column!="TRUE") # row numbers other than TRUEs
which(df$column!="TRUE" & df$column!="FALSE") # again, won't return NAs
```

Comment: I will look into `replace()`: thank you for the suggestion. To address some of your other comments: my data frame doesn't contain `TRUE` or `FALSE` or `NA` values. `TRUE` or `FALSE` are a result of the `if` statement in my code.