# How to replace values in a data frame with another value

Tags: r, dataframe

I have huge data set. The columns contain values like `A,B,C,D,E,F,G,H` and I need to replace them with `1,2,3,4...`

```
[1] "C" "C" "C" "C" "C" "A" "H" "G" "G" "G" "G" "G" "G" "G" "C" "C" "C" "C" "C"
[20] "C" "B" "B" "B" "H" "H" "H" "H" "H" "H" "G" "C" "A" "A" "A" "A" "A" "A" "A"
[30]----
```

Another similar problem is values in one column are more than `1000` and I need to replace them by unique numbers.

Comment: change to factors and convert to numeric (`as.numeric(factor(LETTERS))`) works for your example case

Answer (score 0):

try `replace`

[replace function examples](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11811027/replace-function-examples)

in your case e.g.

```
replace(df, "A", 1)
```

Comment: what about when there is large number of unique values that need to change with unique number?

Comment: please provide reproducible example

Comment: my the data frame is like this which contains different values but it is so huge some portion is like this
df=
[1] "C01" "C02" "C01" "C05" "C04" "A01" "H10" "G10" "G30" "G12" "G10" "G01" "G20" "G30" "C50" "C50" "C32" "C43" "C10"<br>
[20] "C01" "B03" "B01" "B01" ....
output could be like this but doest have to be, because one particular value has one unique number for example for "C01" could be 301 "C02" could be 302 and so on 
df=
[1] "301" "302" "301" "305" "304" "101" "810" "710" "730" "712" "710" "701" "720" "730" "350" "350" "332" "343" "310"<br>
[20] "301" "203" "201" "201" ....