# gsub works but replace does not

Tags: r, string

This is a simple stupid test put together to explain what was happening with my code.  Why does `replace` simply spit back what is fed into it instead of actually replacing the content?  It is because of this unexpected behavior that I am now using `gsub` instead.

Examples:

```
> replace(x="cat", "a", "o")
          a 
"cat"   "o" 

> gsub("a", "o", "cat")
[1] "cot"
```

Comment: What does `?replace` tell you? It isn't a string substitution function. This question might help: https://stackoverflow.com/q/11811027/4996248

Comment: help seems to agree with how I used it but I find that R help is often not written for novices:  `replace replaces the values in x with indices given in list by those given in values. If necessary, the values in values are recycled.`  Based on the writeup, I would expect output of `cot` or faulty output showing me how I misused the arguments, not what I am getting.

Comment: just checked the link in your comment.  I see how it works now.  I had thought you could pass in a single value because I thought I had used it before with dplyr but was probably misremembering.

Comment: `str(replace(x="cat", "a", "o"))` will show you what `replace` does here. I do find it surprising that it works that way. R isn't always intuitive.

Comment: If you really wanted to use `replace` then you would need to do it along these lines: `s <- strsplit("cat", "")[[1]]; paste(replace(s, s == "a", "o"), collapse = "")`