# Make the x axis points in year rather than 2005.5

Tags: r, ggplot2

this is the code

```
ggplot(new_long_seabirds, aes(fill= Fishing_trend, y=count, x=Category))+
   geom_bar(position="stack", stat="identity")+
                labs(x = 'Year', y = 'Number of catches (000)', title = 'Estimated Sea bird by catch by fish trend from 2003-2014')+
              scale_fill_brewer(palette="Spectral")+
              theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 30, vjust = 1, hjust=1))
```

but makes this graph
[image]

instead of points 2003-2014

how do i make the x axis points 2003-2014

Comment: either you have a proper date column ([see for example here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46993898/converting-numbers-to-month-year-in-r-ggplot2))and pass this as your x, or you add `+scale_x_continuous(breaks = 2003:2014)`

Comment: If you share your data using `dput`, we can reproduce and show you the results.